ROS1 bag file: UnicodeDecodeError
I have some .bag files that might be corrupted. Unfortunately, the SSD went down, and some of the .bag files were recovered, but they now return a UnicodeDecodeError when running rosbag info:
root@ros2:~# rosbag info /Downloads/datarec/file.bag 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/bin/rosbag", line 35, in <module>
    rosbag.rosbagmain()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 1032, in rosbagmain
    cmds[cmd](argv[2:])
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 179, in info_cmd
    b = Bag(arg, 'r', skip_index=not options.freq)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 467, in __init__
    self._open(f, mode, allow_unindexed)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 1428, in _open
    if   mode == 'r': self._open_read(f, allow_unindexed)
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 1456, in _open_read
    self._version = self._read_version()
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 1564, in _read_version
    version_line = self._file.readline().rstrip().decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 12: invalid continuation byte

Looking at a similar file from the same sensor but on a different drive, the file appears to be perfectly fine. When viewing the binary data of the working and non-working .bag files, I noticed significant differences:
Correct bag file:

Corrupted (?) file:

Does anyone have experience opening or recovering these .bag files? Thanks!
